# AWS cloudfront PUT request to update s3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on an application to upload photos to s3 bucket. I know I can do that by fetching presigned url and upload the photo using that url. I want to reduce the number of requests and hence wanted to use cloudfront signed cookies , form the cloudfront url in the javascript and upload the photo to s3. Is there any documentation for this? AWS documentation seems to be vague.

Answer (score 0):

Check this part of CloudFront OAI [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4):

> If you want to submit PUT requests to CloudFront to upload objects to your Amazon S3 bucket, you must add an `x-amz-content-sha256` header to the request, and the header value must contain a `SHA256` hash of the body of the request.